# sql table partition best practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, partition

I have done a table partition for existing table. 
can you advice on the best optimization of this since my transaction log is getting full on running the below table partition query

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [pfDimHeader_HIST](nvarchar(6)) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES ( N'201401', N'201501', N'201601', N'201602', N'201603', N'201604', N'201605', N'201606', N'201607', N'201608', N'201609', N'201610', N'201611', N'201612', N'201701', N'201702', N'201703', N'201704', N'201705', N'201706', N'201707')

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [psDimHeader_HIST] AS PARTITION [pfDimHeader_HIST] TO ([PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY])

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_psDimHeader_HIST_636336478362776789] ON [cdw].[DimHeader_HIST]
(
    [ReportingPeriod]
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [psDimHeader_HIST]([ReportingPeriod])

DROP INDEX [ClusteredIndex_on_psDimHeader_HIST_636336478362776789] ON [cdw].[DimHeader_HIST]

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Considering all your reporting period values are ints, why are you storing  and querying them as varchar(6)?

Answer (score 0):

[0] Generally speaking, to lower impact on transaction log, transactions should be smaller. So, instead of using a single transaction to create index and then to deleted (the same index; it makes no sense to me - at least in this moment) you could use two separate transactions (for example).

[1] I would use following query

```
SELECT db.name, db.log_reuse_wait_desc
FROM sys.databases db
WHERE db.name = DB_NAME()
```

to see the main cause of log size increase.

[2] The most probable causes are [2.1] database recovery model is `FULL`/`BULK LOGGED`(same as `FULL` recovery model but optimised for `BULK` operations) and [2.2] missing of log backups and/or [2.3] low frequency log backups. In this case I would create a maintenance plan for backup transaction log or [if exists] I would execute the SQL Agent job.

Note: if the answer isn't clear enough please comment.